# Fortify Cross-Site Scripting: DOM issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fortify

How to fix this issues for last two lines?
Sink: jQuery()
Enclosing Method: handleFilter()
Taint Flags: WEB, XSS

```
 function handleFilter(panelId, textFilterId) {
        var text = $('#' + textFilterId).val();
        if(text === ''){
            $('.removedByFilter').css('display', 'visible');
        } else {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            $('.removedByFilter').css('display', 'visible');
            $('.' + panelId + ' .ui-treetable-data tr').removeClass('removedByFilter');
            $('.' + panelId + ' .ui-treetable-data tr td label:not([title*=' + text + '])').parent().parent('tr').addClass('removedByFilter');
            $('.' + panelId + ' .ui-treetable-data tr td label:not([title*=' + text + '])').parent().parent('tr').css( 'display', 'none' );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any user input or data that can be inserted, to avoid DOM XSS you can use js encoder <%=Encoder.encodeForJS(Encoder.encodeForHTML(untrustedData))%>. For more information you can read https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html.

If there can be no user intervention (for the variable in question) i.e. its a system generated value or a hard-coded value then it can considered as false positive. 
Also, values coming DB should be checked.

I hope this answers your question.